# Eclipse icon looks different after has been updated on MAC

Tags: eclipse

[click to see eclipse icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puhH9.png)

Can some one help me. I updated eclipse (had some issue) and icon on MAC Dock looks weird (click on link to open). Project works fine, still done know why. Any advice?

Comment: Possibly some sort of notification - is there anything in the Notification Centre? Eclipse does also show task progress on the icon but it shouldn't persist after the task finishes.

Comment: Thank you for this question. I was looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

It displays the current workspace name.
To disable:

- Open Preferences (⌘+,);
- Search for "workspace" preferences;
- Untick "Show workspace name";

[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osXjj.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me. Appreciated a lot.

Comment: Agreed. This works. @AndreiMalchanau please mark this as the "Answer" to your question.